# Trouble making a POST request - Express

Tags: node.js, express, post

i'm new to the forum and i've been doing a project for my university and i got a problem with my post request. Can anyone help me with this?
I'm using express and mongo.
Here's my code:

**server.js**

```
var express        = require('express');
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var cors           = require('cors');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

var app            = express();
app.use(cors());

const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/futbol', { useMongoClient: true });
require('./Modelos/partidos.js');

app.use(require('./Rutas'));

var router=express.Router();

app.use(router);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('We are live on ' + port);
});
```

**index.js**

```
var router=require('express').Router();

router.use('/api/partidos', require('./partidos'));

module.exports=router;
```

**partidos.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var router = require('express').Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Partido = mongoose.model('partido');

// GET ALL
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  Partido.find({})
    .then(partidos => {
      if(!partidos){ return res.sendStatus(401); }
      return res.json({'partidos': partidos})
  })
  .catch(next);
});

// GET BY ID
router.get('/:_id', (req, res, next) => {
  let _id = req.params._id
  Partido.findById(_id)
    .then(partidos => {
      if(!partidos){ return res.sendStatus(401); }
      return res.json({'partidos': partidos})
  })
  .catch(next);
});

// POST PARTIDO
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  var _id = req.body._id;
  var id_equipo1 = req.body.id_equipo1;
  var nombre_equipo1 = req.body.nombre_equipo1;
  var id_equipo2 = req.body.id_equipo2;
  var nombre_equipo2 = req.body.nombre_equipo2;
  var fecha_inicio = req.body.fecha_inicio;
  var hora_inicio = req.body.hora_inicio;
  res.send("post _id: "+_id+" - id_equipo1: "+id_equipo1+" - nombre_equipo1 "+nombre_equipo1+" - id_equipo2 "+id_equipo2+" - nombre_equipo2 "+nombre_equipo2+" - fecha_inicio "+fecha_inicio+" - hora_inicio "+hora_inicio);
});

module.exports=router;
```

The POST method that is throwing an error is in **partido.js**
I'm also using RestEasy to make my post request with this parameters:

Url: http://localhost:3000/api/partidos

Method: POST

Headers: Content-Type: application

Body:

```
{    
    "_id" : "2",
    "id_equipo1" : "4",
    "nombre_equipo1" : "Independiente",
    "id_equipo2" : "5",
    "nombre_equipo2" : "River",
    "fecha_inicio" : "10/10/17",
    "hora_inicio" : "21:00:00"
}
```

This is the result:

```
{ 
    post _id: undefined,
    id_equipo1: undefined,
    nombre_equipo1: undefined,
    id_equipo2: undefined,
    nombre_equipo2: undefined,
    fecha_inicio: undefined,
    hora_inicio: undefined
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Content-Type should be *application/json*. Double check that.

Comment: Thanks dude, that make the resteasy work.
Now i need to pass the information to the table in mongoDB, any sugestions?

Comment: @JaviGer92 read the following [docs](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose) and this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose) may help as well.